# Align table rows vertically inside table to cover-up entire area

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table that covers-up entire screen and contains variable number of rows.

I would like to know how can i distribute these rows vertically uniformly, so that they take up entire tables' space.

I have tried layout_weight, and weightSum, but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:id="@+id/maintable"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:text="text 1_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 2_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 3_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:text="text 1_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 2_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 3_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:text="text 1_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 2_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="text 3_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks wrong as your are not setting 'fill parent' constraint for the vertical
axis

```
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >
```

should be

```
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. This will cover entire screen with table rows uniformly

grid_layout.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</TableLayout>
```

grid_layout is filled with text views in code as below

```
public class GridLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int NO_OF_ROWS = 5;
    private static final int NO_OF_COLUMS = 5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        TableLayout gridview = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        for (int rowCnt = 0 ; rowCnt < NO_OF_ROWS; rowCnt++) {
             TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
         TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutLP = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
         tableLayoutLP.weight = 1;
         row.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutLP);

        for (int column = 0; column < NO_OF_COLUMS; column++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowLP = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowLP.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
        tableRowLP.weight=1;
        tableRowLP.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tableRowLP);

        tv.setText("YourText");//Add your text here
        row.addView(tv);
        }

        gridview.addView(row);
    }
}
```

}